# Navigation bar title overlap with right buttons

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, navbar, titlebar

I have four buttons which are right-aligned on the navigation bar and title in center. The title text is bigger and it's overlapping with right buttons. How can I set title width so that it shows the three ellipses when text is overflowing?

[image: Check screenshot to see what i actually saying.]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS like the example below:

```
#wrapperDiv {
white-space: nowrap; 
width: 12em; 
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

I arrange a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/svpbe351/

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to use standard solution not custom fixed width css.